# Converting svg to png without changing the pixel values

Tags: python, svg, imagemagick, png

I have been stuck in this problem for some time now. Essentially, I have a bunch of svg images. Each 'child' in the svg file has been labelled with some pixel value. Currently the number of this values is very small and everything is labelled as rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) ... rgb(9.0, 9.0, 9.0), so essentially I have 10 different types of pixels.

Now, I want to convert these images into png format, and more importantly I need the mapping of pixel values to be 1-to-1. Essentially, all pixels that have values rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) in svg files, need to have values rgb(x,x,x) in png files (or even better L(x)); rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) on svg files need to be converted to rgb(y,y,y) on png files (or even better L(y)) and so on. This one to one mapping is a dealbreaker for my application, because this is essentially the ground truth for my work.

By simply writing in the console:

```
    convert test.svg test.png
```

doesn't give me what I want. Checking the historgram of values, it seems that I have 248 unique values instead of 10, and that isn't good for me (despite that the vast majority of them have just a few pixels).

Does anyone know:

- if this can be done.
- how this can be done.

I've tried so far using other libraries like Python's cairosvg but that seems to work even worse. Yes, I know that svg and png are totally different formats.

For clarification, adding an svg and a png file:

svg: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vhcDz1zxeYeGVDSnhfeWplOWs

png: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vhcDz1zxeYUnYzZUtIUmVqVWM

Opening the file in Python, seems that there are 248 unique pixel values, while there should be only 4 (background + three symbols).

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more concrete and actually show a file rather than talk in abstract terms about *"children"*, `L` and `x` and *"types of pixels"* especially given that `svg` files don't even have pixels.

Comment: Without seeing your test files, I can only guess that you are seeing a scaling effect, where PNG pixels are interpolated from the SVG data points.

Comment: Fair point, I added an svg file, and the corresponding png file. @MarkSetchell

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson

Comment: Thanks.  I'm taking a look.  GraphicsMagick produces the same output as your png.  My ImageMagick v6 and v7 are both rejecting the svg file for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request isn't making a lot of sense.  As far as I can see, your sample SVG file only has two colours: black and white (`rgb(255.0, 255.0, 255.0)`). So where does this 10 colours idea come from?

Also the SVG standard does not specify exactly how vector shapes should be converted to pixels.  There will be subtle differences between SVG renderers.

Remember that vector shape edges that pass through the middle of a pixel will produce a grey pixel. This is called anti-aliasing. It is designed to give a smoother look to the edge.  And I imagine that is why you are seeing many more pixel values than you expect.

---

Perhaps what you are saying is that you want a way to disable anti-aliasing?  Some conversion programs may have options to do this.  Alternatively you can try adding the `shape-rendering` attribute to the root `<svg>` tag of your file:

```
<ns0:svg ...(snip)... shape-rendering="crispEdges">
```

However some SVG conversion  programs may not support this attribute.  But you can see it working if you try it in most browsers.

The output generated by turning antialiasing off will not look as good. But perhaps for your purposes you don't care about that.

---

Alternatively, perhaps you are wanting to know how to convert the SVG to a bitmap, whilst limiting the antialiasing to 10 specific levels of grey?  Imagemagick lets you do that.  I am not an Imagemagick user, but apparently you can tell imagemagick to use a specific colour paletter by passing a palette image using the `-map` parameter.

Comment: On the entire dataset, I use 10 colors (9 shades of black, and a white color for background). On the image, I uploaded, there should be 4 different colors (a white one, and three black ones, one for each symbol). Of course, the three black ones are indistinguishable to human eye, but they have different values if you open the file as array.

I used antialiasing, but it didn't change anything, I am still getting more colors than I should.

Comment: Control-F

        fill="rgb(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)"
        fill="rgb(3.0, 3.0, 3.0)"
        fill="rgb(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)"

and you will find the other three colors.

Comment: Also be aware that the values in an `rgb()` colour are supposed to be integers. Some renderers do  not support decimals like `2.0` - eg. Chrome.

Comment: The shape-rendering="crispEdges" seems to kind of work. Now, I get the number of colors correct.

On the other hand, it seems that now the white is 65535 instead of 255 (a number seems to be represented with 2 bytes instead of 1). It isn't a dealbreaker (after all, I can use a mapping for this), but is there a simple way of having everything in range [0, 255]?

Comment: I didn't know that rgb() values should be integers. Changed that, although it doesn't seem to have any difference in the output.

@Paul LeBeau

Comment: If you are still using **ImageMagick** to make the PNG, you can try `convert image.svg PNG8:result.png` or `convert image.svg PNG24:result.png`.

Comment: This seems to work. Of course, I guess that now I need to write a small script that opens each svg file and adds the shape-rendering="crispEdges" but that's the life. Not sure why +antialias doesn't seem to work by itself though. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Ask a new question showing a couple of lines of SVG and how it is supposed to look afterwards and tag it with `sed` and you will get an answer in seconds...

Comment: Thanks, I am going to do that now.

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: Just be aware that if you make that change to all your SVG files, the SVGs will no longer be rendered at their best quality. The shapes will have "jaggy" edges.  If these SVGs are also intended to displayed normally, printed, etc, you will probably want to keep both versions of the files.

Comment: SVG is a vector file and PNG is raster file. You may never get an exact match due to the rasterizing. But the best way would be to supersample. That is set a high density (4*72=288) and then resize back by the inverse fact 1/4 or 25%. This will give smoother edge boundary transitions. So something like `convert -density 288 image.svg -resize 25% PNGxx:image.png` where PNGxx should be PNG24 for 24bit color or PNG32 (if 24-bit color with alpha) of PNG8 (for 8 bit color (less than 256 distinct colors). For better quality try a larger density such as 8*72=576 and then resize by 1/8 or 12.5%.

Answer (score 0):

3 Years but no great solution gg:

I found 2 good ones:

1. in the ImageMagick command line you can use:

   "convert in.svg +antialias out.png"

but be careful my source said that "+" deactivates AA and "-" activates it. But the source is pretty old and this seems strange so. I couldn't try this

2. Inkscape brought a great solution in an update (I tried this in Version 1.0.1):
   in the Advanced Settings for "export png" you can choose Antialiasing directly `"CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE"` works perfectly for me